# How to have single deployment for two different context?

Tags: tomcat

In our environment I am having more than one contexts `(ROOT, myapp, backup)`

The urls `localhost:8080/myapp` & `localhost:8080` need to access the same application `myapp`

To acheive this I am deploying `myapp` application in `tomcat/webapps/ROOT` directory and `tomcat/webapps/myapp` directory.

Is there any way to avoid this multiple deployment? I am using apache `tomcat 7`

Answer (score 1):

you can plcae an index.html in root path that redirects browser to your app url :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=./myapp/">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "./myapp/"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Note: don't tell people to `click` the link, just tell them that it is a link. -->
        If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href='./myapp/'>link to example</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, we have thought about this approach, In my environment redirection is not possible, is there anyway to do in that tomcat configuration level itself?